# How to use XDMCP+GDM and Xnest?

Tags: 10.10, gdm, xdmcp

I have been trying to enable XDMCP on GDM without much success.
Following some instructions I have edited /etc/gdm/custom.conf and added:

```
[daemon]
RemoteGreeter=/usr/lib/gdm/gdm-xdmcp-chooser-slave
[xdmcp]
Enable=true
```

Then restarted gdm and tried to connect both locally and from a remote system with:

```
Xnest :1 -query localhost
Xnest :1 -query remote_system_hostname
```

I just get a black screen instead of the GDM window as expected.
I am missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait for this bug to be fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/669670

Comment: Oh another regression :(

Answer (score 1):

For LightDM which is in the latest Unity based Ubuntus I used this answer: [XDMCP setup for lightdm, ports not listening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90920/xdmcp-setup-for-lightdm-ports-not-listening)

And you will probably need to also add the SeatDefaults setting in the answer i.e.

```
[SeatDefaults]
xserver-allow-tcp=true
```

And you may also need to enable access to your local server by using

```
xhost +<remote hostname>
```

or just

```
xhost +
```

to disable it completely